# WSO2 API Manager versioning APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am looking to change the structure of the URL generated by the WSO2 API Manager for a defined service by switching the position of the version number. For example, the default for a service is

`http://localhost:8020/some_service/1.0.0`

however, I would prefer to have it as

`http://localhost:8020/1.0.0/some_service/`

Answer (score 0):

That URL format is fixed one and generally that is the URL format is followed. If you like to change the format, there is no way, but you can define the version with context and make a preferred url pattern. But again version must be filled.

Answer (score 0):

My 2cts; you could put Apache with mod-proxy and mod-rewrite module or HAProxy in front of WSO2 AM  and user rewrite rules on the URL's.